# Python - Faster Way To Compare Every Item of a Matrix to Every Other Item

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I know there are some other questions that have similar problems, but none that cover what I am looking for. I am looking for a relatively quick way to calculate the similarity of every item in a matrix to every other item. I am testing an NLP technique to measure it's effectiveness at gauging document similarity.

so I have a matrix with rows like this (I currently have it stored as a dictionary, but I could convert it to a matrix I believe):
A = [a1, a2,...,am]
B = [b1, b2,...,bm]
...
N = [n1, n2,...,nm]

My algorithm is that I iterate through each category. Within a category, I iterate through elements in that category. Then, for each element, I iterate through every element in the same category and find the average similarity. For each element I also iterate through every element outside of the category and find the average similarity. I continuously average the averages of each element, which provides me a kind of "meta-average" of how similar inCategoy documents are to each other compared to outCategory documents. Here is my code:

```
class SimilarityTesting:
def __init__(self,documents,space,documentdictionary, tfidf=None,hes=False,printer=False):
    self.documents = documents
    self.space = space
    self.documentDictionary = documentdictionary
    self.tfidf = tfidf
    self.hes = hes
    self.printer = printer
    self.pairwiseDictionary = {}


    #self.testingExecute()


def testingExecute(self):


    withinCategorySum = 0
    outsideCategorySum = 0
    i=0

    for categoryLabel, categoryDocuments in self.documents.iteritems():
        categoryAverage,setAverage = self.categoryComparison(categoryLabel, categoryDocuments)

        withinCategorySum+=categoryAverage
        outsideCategorySum +=setAverage
        i+=1

    withinAverage = withinCategorySum/i
    outsideAverage = outsideCategorySum/i
    ratio = withinAverage/outsideAverage

    print "The average similarity of documents within their category is %s" % withinAverage
    print "The average similarity of documents not within their category is %s" % outsideAverage
    print "The Ratio of Difference is %s" % ratio
    print
    return withinAverage, outsideAverage, ratio

def categoryComparison(self,categoryLabel,categoryDocuments):
    if self.printer: print "CATEGORY ", categoryLabel
    categorySum = 0
    nonCategorySum = 0
    i =0


    nonCategory = [x for x in self.documents.values() if x != categoryDocuments]
    flatNoncategory = [val for sublist in nonCategory for val in sublist]

    #I believe this is the best place to do parallelization
    for element in categoryDocuments:
        categorySim = self.itemPairCompare(element,categoryDocuments)
        categorySum+=categorySim

        nonCategorySim = self.itemPairCompare(element,flatNoncategory)
        nonCategorySum+=nonCategorySim

        i+=1
    categoryAverage = categorySum/i
    noncategoryAverage = nonCategorySum/i

    if self.printer:
        print
        print "AVERAGE SIMILARITY OF CATEGORY ITEM-IN-CATEGORY SIMILARTY ", categoryAverage
        print "AVERAGE SIMILART OF CATEGORY'S ITEM-NOT-IN-CATEGORY SIMILARITY ", noncategoryAverage
        print
        print

    return categoryAverage,noncategoryAverage


def itemPairCompare(self,item, listDocuments):

    #print "ITEM WITHIN CATEGORY"

    sum = 0
    i = 0

    for value in listDocuments:
        if item != value:

            itemID = self.documentDictionary[str(item)]
            valueID = self.documentDictionary[str(value)]

            pair1ID = itemID + valueID
            pair2ID = valueID + itemID

            if pair1ID in self.pairwiseDictionary:
                sim = self.pairwiseDictionary[pair1ID]
            elif pair2ID in self.pairwiseDictionary:
                sim = self.pairwiseDictionary[pair2ID]

            if self.tfidf:
                vec1_tfidf=self.tfidf[item]
                vec1 = self.space[vec1_tfidf]

                vec2_tfidf = self.tfidf[value]
                vec2 = self.space[vec2_tfidf]

                sim = matutils.cossim(vec1, vec2)

            elif self.hes:
                vec1=self.space[item]
                vec2=self.space[value]
                dense1 = gensim.matutils.sparse2full(vec1, self.space.num_topics)
                dense2 = gensim.matutils.sparse2full(vec2, self.space.num_topics)
                hes = np.sqrt(0.5 * ((np.sqrt(dense1) - np.sqrt(dense2))**2).sum())
                sim = 1-hes
                self.pairwiseDictionary[pair1ID] = sim

            else:
                sim = matutils.cossim(self.space[item],self.space[value])
                self.pairwiseDictionary[pair1ID] = sim
            #print sim

            sum+=sim
            i+=1

    average  = sum/i
    if self.printer: print "ITEM'S AVERAGE SIMILARITY TO ITEMS IN CATEGORY IS ", average
    return average
```

This code is downstream of a larger pipeline that involves tokenization and conversion of my documents to a bag-of-words, so I can't really provide an example matrix to run it on. I provided the code more as a way to show where I'm at right now. Basically, I want to know if I can create a matrix of vectors, and then use numpy to compare every vector to every other vector more quickly than iteration.

I managed to save some time by creating a dictionary of element-pairs that already occur to avoid duplicating calculation. However, this thing still takes a really long time to run ( O(NM^2), i believe), and I'm trying to figure out ways to optimize or parallize it. Is this something that NumPy would be good at? Also, I've read that multi core processing is kind of difficult with python. Is this something that multiprocessing would struggle with? Does anyone have any advice on how to do this in a more optimal way? Thanks

Comment: Numpy code is vectorized, with underlying implementations in C. If you use loops to iterate over data, you will see little to no improvements. If you use the embedded numpy functions to compare arrays, you could potentially gain a lot of processing time

Comment: I can see that you put effort in writing your first question, but it is way too long and probably has a lot of information that's not needed for answering the question. Please make a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - other than that, I agree with Ben. numpy `==` works pairwise for arrays.

Comment: Yeah, I figured if I was going to implement numpy I would have to fundamentally refactor my code. What are some of the embedded functions that would help me with what I'm looking for? I'm not that familiar with the library

Comment: I know my code chunk is kind of large, but I couldn't figure out a way to make it more concise. I've gotten yelled at on here before for not being specific enough, so I thought it was best to err on the side of sharing too much

Comment: The problem is that there are no sample matrices I can paste into my interpreter and no expected result I can compare my answer to.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can tweak it to work with sample matrices. This is downstream of a larger pipeline that involves tokenization and other NLP wrapping techniques. I provided the code as an example of what I was trying to accomplish--sorry if that was confusing. I'm mostly wondering if there's an easy way in numpy to compare every element in a matrix to every other element

Comment: You have a lot of functions for that in numpy, a.o. ==, allclose, greater ... Combined with slicing indexes, you can achieve lots of things. Depends on what exactly you need to achieve.

Comment: I believe that scipy has what I'm looking for, with cdist(A,A,metric='cosine'). Is there anyway to use a custom metric, though? Gensim's cosine similarity works for BoW vectors, and I don't think that scipy's will work for that.

Comment: It looks like I can pass my own function in cdist.